# SQL update (case) multiple values

Tags: sql

i need to update different columns based on their values:

```
UPDATE tablename

set date1 = case
    when mytime < '01.08.2020' then mytime
end,
set date2 = case
    when mytime < '01.08.2020' then mytime
end

where something = 1;
```

In the 2nd set block im getting the error, that the column (date2) is invalid.

Comment: `set` only occurs once in an `update`.

Comment: For some databases (like SQLite3), you must use dates in YYYY-MM-DD format to have accurate sorting and comparisons.

Comment: @tonypdmtr In almost all cases it is better to use date literals `date '2020-11-10'` or it's equivalent not to deal with cultural representation of the same data (because in one day someone can change the default behaviour or setting).

Comment: @astentx That's what I said.  But the format has to be YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @tonypdmtr This is not the same. In Oracle. for example, [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) is exact word `date` followed by date in format `yyyy-mm-dd`. So just formatting text will not work sometimes: `SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select *
  2  from dual
  3  where current_date < '2020-12-31';
where current_date < '2020-12-31'
                     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `set` multiple times for multiple columns

```
UPDATE tablename set 
    date1 = case when mytime < '01.08.2020' then mytime end, 
    date2 = case when mytime < '01.08.2020' then mytime end
where something = 1;
```

Comment: Note that on most databases, the date literals you used (and so did the OP) would be bogus, unless the date were stored as text, and in that case, it wouldn't sort properly.  You should comment on this.